# API JSON Response to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to take this JSON response (It is just a sample of the response)

```
[
    [
        {
            "session_id": "f02f8b6670a2811b2ee0cfd770a871f6",
            "url": "https://something.bob.com/courses/10546/external_tools/44",
            "context_type": "Course",
            "asset_type": null,
            "controller": "external_tools",
            "action": "show",
            "interaction_seconds": null,
            "created_at": "2021-10-25T02:43:42Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-25T02:43:42Z",
            "developer_key_id": null,
            "user_request": null,
            "render_time": 0.223835,
            "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36",
            "asset_user_access_id": 11535927,
            "participated": false,
            "summarized": null,
            "http_method": "get",
            "remote_ip": "184.88.22.85",
            "id": "8e40f170-1225-43c6-8796-9a8ad6f1c351",
            "contributed": false,
            "links": {
                "user": 9526,
                "context": 10546,
                "asset": null,
                "real_user": null,
                "account": 1
            },
            "app_name": null
        },
```

And convert it to a CSV that looks like

```
session_id,url,context_type
f02f8b66,google.com,course
```

and so on throughout the response.

Here is what I have so far

```
headers = {
       'Authorization': key
}

data_set = []
next_check = 'default'

r = requests.get(domain + "/api/v1/users/9526/page_views?start_time=" + start + "&end_time=" + end + "&per_page=10", headers=headers)
next_ = r.links['next']['url']
d = r.json()
data_set.append(d)

while next_check != 'null':
       r = requests.get(next_, headers=headers)
       next_d = r.json()
       data_set.append(next_d)
       next_check = r.links.get('next', 'null')
       if next_check != 'null':
              next_ = r.links['next']['url']



file = open("requests.json", "w")
file.write(json.dumps(data_set, indent=4))
file.close()

pdObj = pd.read_json("requests.json", orient="index")
print(pdObj)
csvData = pdObj.to_csv('response.csv')
```

And this is my response:
'list' object has no attribute 'values'

I am kinda lost on this one. I looked at the Pandas documentation and I thought I was doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

actually this is a list of json.so you need to convert this list to csv by using pandas

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(res)  #this res is the json response

csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
```